# Can't make any table joins in query

Tags: sql, join, ssms

I am trying to write a simple query that joins two tables, but when I type any kind of join `Inner Join`, `Outer join`, `Left Join`, etc the text is greyed out instead  of blue.

I even cut my query down to simple

```
SELECT *
from TableA
Outer Join TableB on TableA.column1 = TableB.column1
```

... and the text is still greyed out. If I try running the query anyway, it kicks out an error:

> incorrect syntax near keyword join

Comment: "left", "right", or "full" outer join? You need to tell which one.

Comment: Which outer join?  Maybe your query is too simple.  You cut the word (left, right, full).

Comment: Any kind of join? First of all you should think about which join you actually need. Are you saying that even `SELECT * from TableA Inner Join TableB on TableA.column1 = TableB.column1` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

try like below is that left, right or full outer? i used left just for example

```
    SELECT a.*,b.* from TableA a left Outer Join 
     TableB b on a.column1 = b.column1
```

Comment: howdo you know its a left outer join

Comment: Or "full outer join".

Answer (score 1):

Any of these will work:

```
SELECT * from TableA LEFT Outer Join TableB on TableA.column1 = TableB.column1

SELECT * from TableA RIGHT Outer Join TableB on TableA.column1 = TableB.column1

SELECT * from TableA FULL Outer Join TableB on TableA.column1 = TableB.column1
```

You need to pick one of these. There isn't a unique type of `OUTER JOIN`.